# Java JMX invoking method returning javax.ws.rs.core.Response object not working (get NotSerializableException)

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jmx, spring-jmx

This is the JMX bean invoke (that fails) :

```
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn

//some code going on ...    
...

response = (Response) mbeanConn.invoke(myBean,"example", null, null);
```

It throws the exception :

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseIm
```

When looking in my code the function that is invoked is :

```
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

   @ManagedOperation
   public Response example() throws GeneralException {
    //do some things with the response object
    ...
    return response.build();
   }
```

From my understanding I have a problem that the abstract class javax.ws.rs.core.Response isn't Serialized.

Any ideas how to bypass this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMX uses java serialization to transfer arguments and operation results. Even if the class was `Serializable` you'd need it on the client's classpath.

There is no solution except adding an operation that renders the object as, say, a String. If you are lucky, you can use `toString()` but if the object hasn't overridden `Object.toString()`, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: in the end Ive built a response that implements Serializable, thanks